# Multiple replace in AWK for tsv file [REFACTOR]

Tags: bash, awk

I have the followings lines in my `file.sh` file:

```
awk '$2 != "$ID1$"' myfile2.tsv > output && mv output myfile3.tsv
awk '$2 != "$ID2$"' myfile3.tsv > output && mv output myfile3.tsv
awk '$2 != "$ID3$"' myfile3.tsv > output && mv output myfile3.tsv
awk '$2 != "$ID4$"' myfile3.tsv > output && mv output myfile3.tsv
awk '$2 != "$ID5$"' myfile3.tsv > output && mv output myfile3.tsv
awk '$2 != "$ID6$"' myfile3.tsv > output && mv output myfile3.tsv
awk '$2 != "$ID7$"' myfile3.tsv > output && mv output myfile3.tsv
awk '$2 != "$ID8$"' myfile3.tsv > output && mv output myfile3.tsv
awk '$2 != "$ID9$"' myfile3.tsv > output && mv output myfile4.tsv
...
```

This just work like a charm but i need refactor this to some like this following because i have several lines (+600):

```
awk '$2 != "$ID1$", $2 != "$ID2$", $2 != "$ID3$" ...' myfile3.tsv > output && mv output myfile3.tsv
```

I have tried everything but I can't find the key with the correct syntax.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It seems as most of those commands could be deleted as they all overwrite `myfile3.tsv`. You would be left with only the last two.

Comment: Are the ID numbers always consecutive (e.g. 1 to 659 or whatever your 600+ number is)?

Comment: @Kusalananda no, the all is not overwrite. Take the same file like input and output respecting the previous changes.

Comment: @EdMorton no, is just for example, i replaced all the values for privacy issues.

Comment: Thats fine to replace them but then use dummy values that look like your real data rather than making it look like they're all consecutive as that leads us to suggest answers that will work for your example but that won't work for your real data.

Comment: You say you have 600+ of these "IDs" to compare $2 against - are they listed in a file our output from a command or is there some other way to get them as a list to pass to awk? Or is there a predetermined order for IDs that we can calculate within the script?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want is as follows. The lim variable you fill in to get the required number of parameters.

```
awk -F '\t' -v lim=9 '
  BEGIN {
    OFS = FS
    for (i=1; i<=lim; i++) a["$ID"  i "$"]
  }
  $2 in a {next}
1'  yourfile.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect the comma operator to do in this case, what does it according to the manual?

If you have tried everything, have you also tried the AND operator to create an AND condition?

```
awk '$2 != "$ID1$" && $2 != "$ID2$"' myfile3.tsv > output
```

If you want something fancy, you can use an array in awk.

If your search terms don't occur in other parts of the line, you can use `grep -v`.

Comment: The OP mentioned they have over 600 such "ID"s to match against so writing out comparisons for them all explicitly would be a problem with any tool.

Comment: The 600 IDs have to be specified one way or other, and this is exactly what OP asked for, OP just used `,` instead of `&&`. The other answer, while upvoted, ignores that OP most likely doesn't want to filter against the literal string "ID" + number.

Comment: Not matter how the IDs are specified you wouldn't do it this way as it's lengthy, inefficeitn, and has too much code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't generate the IDs and instead have to list them manually then it'd be:

```
awk -v ids='$ID1$ $ID2$' '
    BEGIN { split(ids,tmp); for (i in tmp) idarr[tmp[i]] }
    !($2 in idarr)
' file
```

or if they're stored each on a separate line in a file named `ids`:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { idarr[$1]; next }
    !($2 in idarr)
' ids file
```

or some such similar approach that ends with a hash lookup.